# Sub-project does not find Swift modules installed via Pods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I've created a react native module `RNKin`. And I tried to install the dependencies of this module/library via Pods.

Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'demo_pods' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  # Pods for demo_pods

  pod 'KinEcosystem', '0.5.4'
  pod 'JWT', '3.0.0-beta.11'
  pod 'Alamofire'

end
```

The sub-project (my RNKin library) import those pod frameworks (KinEcosystem, Alamofire, JWT) in the .swift files (as you can see in the screenshot)
But when I try to build the demo_pods project it fails with the error "No such module xxx".

[image]

I tried every combination of framework/header search path. And I dont know whats wrong :(

The fully installed project can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixy0tip3etb8sb3/demo_pods.zip?dl=0
(pods and node_modules already installed)

After some days of trial&error I post this in hope someone can help me, that would be awesome!!! =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fixed my `Podfile`:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!

workspace 'demo_pods.xcworkspace'

def shared_pods
  pod 'KinEcosystem', '0.5.4'
  pod 'JWT', '3.0.0-beta.11'
  pod 'Alamofire'
end

target 'demo_pods' do
  shared_pods

  target 'RNKin' do
    project '../node_modules/react-native-kin/ios/RNKin.xcodeproj'
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `Podfile` like this.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'demo_pods' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  # Pods for demo_pods

  pod 'KinEcosystem', '0.5.4'
  pod 'JWT', '3.0.0-beta.11'
  pod 'Alamofire'

  target 'RNKin' do
      inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

If it does not help please replay.

Comment: thx for your reply. But this did not work: 
pod install: **[!] Unable to find a target named `RNKin`, did find `demo_pods`, `demo_podsTests`, `demo_pods-tvOS`, and `demo_pods-tvOSTests`.**